# Как удалить все строки кроме первой в python?

Tags: python, текст, txt

Есть .txt файл с определенным текстом.
Задача - удалить все строки кроме первой. То есть, если текст выглядит так:

*Строка номер один*

*Строка номер два*

*Строка номер три*

*Строка номер четыре*

Сделать так:

*Строка номер один*

Comment: `with open('файл.txt', 'rb+') as fp: fp.readline(); fp.truncate()`

Comment: (впрочем, конкретно такой ↑ вариант поведёт себя некорректно на кодировке UTF-16LE)

Comment: @andreymal Даже если открыть файл именно в этой кодировке?

Comment: @CrazyElf в текстовом режиме для truncate открывать нельзя, похоже, буфер портит всю малину или что-то типа того

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
mylist = list()
with open('mytxtfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        mylist.append(line)
print(mylist[0].strip('\n'))
```

может и попроще можно как то, но тут первое что пришло на ум.